# Ignore certain file from pending changes

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

Here is my problem. I have a certain files from the solution (let's say Web.config) that I've changed and will never want to check-in since the changes are referring to my machine only. Is there a way to say in TFS to ignore changes in a certain file and remove it from pending changes window. Of course, I can skip this file in every check-in, but there is always a change to forget and check-in by mistake. For example, there is a similar ignore list in AnkhSVN.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some parts of `{app,web}.config` files can be delegated to another file. Notably `<connectionStrings>`.

In your `app.config` or `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="LocalConnectionStrings.config" />
```

in `LocalConnectionStrings.config` have (`<connectionStrings>` is the root element):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- For the application's operations. -->
    <add name="Application"
         connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True;Network Library=dbmssocn"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Thus each developer has a `LocalConnectionStrings.config` which is in the project, but not in source control set with their private settings while the `{web,app}.config` has shared settings. Unfortunately this only works with a limited set of system defined configuration elements.

Answer (score 6):

One workaround could be to remove the readonly attribute on the web.config in the windows explorer then edit it in notepad:

- It won't appear in the pending
  changes
- It's still in the source
  control

Ugly but simple solution.

Comment: You can edit in VS without checkout if you select Allow Editing... option in Tools | Options | General | Documents.

Comment: Note this trick does NOT work with "Local Workspaces" in TFS 2012+.

Answer (score 4):

The best practice concerning configuration files, TFS and different developer machines is (hem hem)...

All your developers should have the same dev environment. It's the only way to manage web.config files in TFS, and it has a lot of added benefits:

- Nomore "but it work on my computer"
- its friend the dreaded "I don't understand what dependencies are required. It doesn't compile anymore."
- You won't regret the famous "Ah! I forgot to tell you, I invented a MyWonderfullApplicationConfigSection and you should define it in your web.config, but I won't tell you how."
- It will really help setting up a build environment or a deployment.

Ok, it isn't really easy, I know that different developers like different settings... but it's a good idea to standardize the dev platform. It's really worth it.

Comment: -1 bad idea. What if you have a multi-tier architecture that uses the web config to figure out wsdl end points? what about error emails? what about  devs don't like batch compile? Standardizing the dev web config is not feasible in many situations.

Comment: I said it's not always easy to implement. However, you should note that if you have a standardised dev platform, the wsdl endpoints are not an issue anymore (these become standardized) And if they are not... you will have issues nevertheless. I don't see the point of error emails on a developer platform. Switch them on on production only. If different dev need different compilation config, it's fine: Compilation configurations exists exactly for that. Beware however of unnoticed changes on dependencies from other developers.

Comment: While it's true we can argue about all these points, they don't make may answer less pertinent in any way... Standardising web development platform has a lot of benefits. And it could go as far as using a common regularly updated VHD

Comment: Also, note that I said "should" and not "must". For a lot of reason (explained above) I feel that it's a good thing to do. I understand however that it's not always possible.

Comment: Fair enough. update your answer and I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

For our work in VS 2005/2008 we have multiple checkout turned on, and we just never check in the web.config.

For the hassle of trying to do funky things to not have something checked in, we just never check it in. In the odd case that one of those files is checked in, well it's  a quick "Hey guys I screwed up".

On the other hand, you can tell TFS to exclude a file from source control. This will will need to exist on all computers because solutions / projects will still look for that file.

http://arcware.net/2007/04/12/how-to-exclude-files-from-tfs-source-control/

You can also modify the .SLN / project file.
I have done this method with testing projects where I don't want to have to fix other peoples tests just to run my own, so I removed my testing project from TFS, while keeping others intact.

Comment: As I have stated the "Hey guys I screwed up" doesn't suits me (to be precise - I'm doing it this way right now, but I look for more convenient way). Excluding the file from source control also is not an option.

Comment: Link died. Not in archive.org. Painfully, [author says](http://arcware.net/reboot/), "*This might surprise some people, but all of my previous content is gone. Everything I’ve written before, the entire decade of 2004 – 2014, is no longer available. No posts, no comments, nothing.*" Who says public content on the web can't die? ;^)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy of the files you don't want to check in, undo their check out, and replace them with the copy. Since the change was made from outside VS, it won't be checked out, so it won't be in the Pending Changes list.

(I know this is an old question, but I'm sure someone looking for a way to do this could use this answer)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing for ignore, but the best thing is, after checkin, you can use web based login or some different machine where you have not mapped your source code tree, and you can delete the unwanted files from your source code tree and visual studio will not checkin those files next time you modify them.

You can also put file in folder and modify your project file in xml editor to include your file in your project, visual studio will not add files to source code control that were added manually by editing xml of project file.

Comment: I've considered this variant too, but this file should be under source control. There is no way to exclude it, because this will broke some other functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of studio are you using?

If you are on 2010, then you can use web config transformations.  That way you can have different web.config files depending on the environment.  For example, development, testing, production..

If you are on 2008, we usually had a main web.config file pointing to our development stuff and a web.production.config file pointing to production.  During deploy we delete the web.config and rename web.production.config.

Comment: I'm using 2010 but the changes are machine specific not environment specific. For example for dev environment the dev's web.config is different for everyone of my colleagues.

Comment: @anthares: I'm guessing each of you are running your own local sql server?  You could build on the transformation idea and just add a configuration for each dev..  Or, just work off of the same settings.  Personally, having dealt with the issues in both types of environments I prefer a common SQL server approach... It seems less of a hassle.