# How to ignore files on Visual Studio Team Services (not for local server)

Tags: version-control, tfs, azure-devops

I want to ignore files on Team Services version like web.config or app.config.
Because they are related with user and local db's. So I wanna ignore them when I check in all solution.
I searched little bit but all informations are about local servers. So I can't apply this solutions.

Comment: I suspect there's some confusion in the terminology here - if you were finding articles talking about how to ignore files:  `.tfignore` works for *local workspaces*, which is a particular type of mode that TFS operates in.  It is independent of *where* the TFS server is physically located, be it a "local server" or Visual Studio Online.

Comment: Also, I don't know of any case where it's a good idea to not have web.config and app.config in source control.

Comment: Yea maybe it's a solution but I wanted to learn it if we are using same db but for locals. And sometimes our sql configurations are different. And I guess best way to do is @Jo-Pierre's solution. So we just add two more files to solution (not source control) and redirect for connection string. So we don't need to change anything now. So it's cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add files to store details outside of web.config and then Undo the Include in the Pending Checkins, original answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3883663/585248

This answer relates to having exclusive checkouts ... if you use Local Sever then you can use ignore files. Exclusive checkouts you would need to set it to Server and try the solution from the link above. Tested and works.

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of TFS (which includes VS Online), the preferred approach is to use a .tfignore file.

You simply check-in a .tfignore file and TFS uses that to determine which files/paths/extensions/etc to ignore and not include in TFS.

You can read more about tfignore files here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore

Comment: Definitely so.  It should be noted that `.tfignore` works with any *local workspace* - regardless of whether the server is "local" or Visual Studio Online.

Comment: I tried creating the .tfignore file but had no option for it. I never had the option in Team Explorer to see the Detected changes to get the  Promote Candidate Changes dialog. Also my workspace is set to Server not local.

Comment: What version of TFS/VS are you using?

Comment: VS2013 Pro with TFS online (visualstudio.com)

Comment: What about exclusive checkouts in VS2013 with TFS online? Is that possible to do that when you use local workspaces as we are more than 1 person ...

Comment: I recommend not using exclusive checkouts (and no it's not possible with local workspaces).

Comment: Then how we compare our changes and combine them? And what about more than one person working on same file? @DylanSmith